# nfs mount fails in Ubuntu 10, but not with -v

Tags: linux, nfs, fstab

```
(1)  mount    -t nfs remotehost:/remotedir localmountpoint -o owner,rw
(2)  mount -v -t nfs remotehost:/remotedir localmountpoint -o owner,rw
```

(1) Used to work with Ubuntu 9 and now fails with Ubuntu 10 (2.6.32-21-generic kernel) with the error:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

Strangely, adding -v (verbose) in (2) makes the problem go away.

This is currently a blocker for me because the fstab line:

```
remotehost:/remotedir localmountpoint nfs owner,rw   0 0
```

causes the same error (I don't believe I can specify verbose in fstab).

Is this a bug in mount or are my options really incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Are NFS versions between boxes the same?  I would think Ubuntu 10 would have changed the default to nfsv4.  Maybe try specifying nfs3 in the fstab entry, assuming your other node is using nfs3.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying proto=udp seems to fix this:

```
(command line) mount -t nfs remotehost:/remotedir localmountpoint -o owner,rw,proto=udp    
(fstab)        remotehost:/remotedir localmountpoint nfs owner,rw,proto=udp   0 0
```